# Python Image Detection PDF

Tags: python, pdf, image-processing

How to detect Image in the PDF file(Python).

I have to detect that image is present in the PDF file or not.
Is there any way to do so.

i have tried PyPdf but not Successful with that. please help me

thanks
any response Appreciated

Comment: Just to clarify, the asker's question is not too bad: He wants some sample code to use python to extract the image contents (if it exists) of a PDF file. The answer provided does accurately answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is PDFMiner. It also has a [Python-API](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/programming.html). This can help you searching for images. By using:

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator

# Set parameters for analysis.
laparams = LAParams()
# Create a PDF page aggregator object.
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
for page in doc.get_pages():
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    # receive the LTPage object for the page.
    layout = device.get_result()
```

`layout` is a `LTPage`-object, which basically is a tree of all layout-objects on a page. You can walk along all branches of this tree and check if there is a `LTImage`-object somewhere - then you know there's an image.

PDFMiner only works with Python 2.x.

Comment: Your welcome, let me know if you succeeded.

Comment: There's a nice "summary" of the pdfminer's ability to loop through these different LTImage/LTPage objects here: http://denis.papathanasiou.org/2010/08/04/extracting-text-images-from-pdf-files/